# running ubuntu command from PHP code

Tags: php, command-line

I want to convert a pdf into html in `PHP` by running this command

```
pdftohtml -i -c test/invoice.pdf test/invoice.html
```

but it's not working using this `PHP` code

```
$data=exec('pdftohtml -i -c test/invoice.pdf test/invoice.html');
```

Comment: Does your apache/nginx user have write permission?

Comment: yes it have , should i have to give path or any thing else ?

Comment: Yes, add the full path to your files in your command

Comment: added no output

Comment: what ends up in invoice.pdf, does it contain the pdf as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved above question by giving permission to folder having issue due to folder is not writable its difficult for me to find because it's not showing any error on my Ubuntu machine, even its error mode and debugging is on.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the command as root.

I had this issue once and ended up writing a script that SSH'd into itself.

```
$this->root_execute('pdftohtml -i -c test/invoice.pdf test/invoice.html');
```

-

```
public function root_execute($command = '')
{
    set_include_path('/path/to/dir/ssh/');
    require_once('Net/SSH2.php');

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2(SSH_HOST);

    if (!$ssh->login(SSH_USER, SSH_PASS)) {
        exit('failed');
    }
    $res = $ssh->exec($command);
    $ssh = null;
    restore_include_path();
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Did you get SSH2?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of error you get after execute the command?
try maybe other feature etc. shell_exec http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide the full path for the `pdftohtml`. For example if you are on linux you can do

```
whereis pdftohtml
```

You may then see `/usr/bin` for example, therefore changing the line to read

```
/usr/bin/pdftohtml -i -c ./test/invoice.pdf ./test/invoice.html
```

This may resolve your issue. If you are on Linux you can also check the logs, for example:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error.log
```

You may be able to track the error this way. Finally another option is to run the php file from the browser and check for output, then try from command line and again check for output. If you can nail down if under both instances there is an issue we would likely be closer to the solution.